# Object.defineProperty to override HTMLElement eventhandler not work on event attributes

Tags: javascript, dom, eventhandler

I want to override HTMLElement's on-event handler method with Object.defineProperty.

here is the code.

```js
var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick');
var originalGet = desc.get;
desc.get = function () {
    console.log('get onclick');
    return originalGet.apply(this, arguments);
}    
var originalSet = desc.set;
desc.set = function() {
    console.log('set onclick', arguments);
    return originalSet.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

The code will work when I add event listener in this way,

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() { 
   console.log("button clicked");
}
```

But will not work when I define the onclick handler in html inline.

`<button onclick="btnClick(event)">ok</button>`

The getter is called, but setter is not called.
I can't figure out why?

Comment: did you define `originalSet` in your real code?

Comment: "*I want to override HTMLElement's on-event handler method*" - I don't think you really want that. What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I agree with Bergi. Unless you're making some experimental project to learn about javascript and DOM, what you're doing is a bad idea. If you **are** experimenting for fun and education, emphasize this in your question. Stackoverflow is unfortunatelly very negative towards experimenting in general.

Comment: Yes, I defined originalSet in my code. And I want to do that because I want to monitor all user operations without modify user code. Some other libraries such as angular/zone.js did the same thing.

Comment: I think maybe the reason is the inline event handler will only evaluated at runtime, when button element is created, the onclick is just a string attribute but not a function.

Comment: This question is useful for browser extensions, for example if you want to write an extension that disallows any webpage from running Javascript during right click to pull up the context menu. However, your example no longer works if it ever did. You need to call Object.defineProperty on the prototype to add the new setters.